# Elasticsearch: bulk insert with array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with elasticsearch now and got problem since beginning.

I got collection from request in node, collection looks something like:

```
[{ eventId: 2, eventName: "Nothing", eventType: 2}...]
```

Collection has ~15000 items. I can't figur eout how to easly place all of these items into elasticsearch (tried with bulk, but bulk api documentation says it needs to be a ndjson format) and I contact with elasticsearch via axios.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As @Lupanoide suggested, if you read the documentation, you need to create ndjson format to execute bulk API. Simply iterate and add new line after each item and your data should look like  like :

`{ eventId: 2, eventName: "Nothing", eventType: 2},

 { eventId: 2, eventName: "Nothing", eventType: 2}`

and save these against a single index and use "POST /indexName/_doc/_bulk"

Comment: I have solved it just by doing `[].map(transform).join('\n')`, and placing bulk action before every item, then passing it as string to post data.